# Changing the Ionic folder structure into separate files and folders

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

my current folder structure is like this:

```
templates/  
          homepage.html
          signin.html

js/
   app.js
   routes.js
   controllers.js
   directives.js
```

but I want to change it to this

```
templates/ 
          homepage/
                    homepage.html
                   homepage.js

          signin/
                    signin.html
                   signin.js
```

I included the new controller in the index.html, I changed the state in the routes file to:

```
    .state('homePage', {
      url: '/homePage',
      templateUrl: 'templates/homePage/jobStore.html',
      controller: 'homePageCtrl'
  })
```

in the homepage.js I wrote this:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('homePageCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```

In my homepage view, I have the following :

```
     <a ui-sref="login" id="loginButton" class=" button button-positive  button-block ">Sign In</a>
```

but I keep getting an error that says loginCtrl is not a function

Comment: did you inject the module `app.controllers` in main module in app.js ? .. you didint mentioned about `loginCtrl` check if `loginCtrl` is used anywhere in your app .

Comment: have you included controller files to index.html ?

Comment: @HardikVaghani I did include the controllers in my application

Comment: @XAVIERK.I loginCtrl is the next page's controller. it goes form the home page to the login page. So the login page has a loginCtrl

Answer (score 0):

First Define module in app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

`app` will be whatever you will define in `ng-app="app"`

and define controller this way (You will not need `angular.module('app.controllers', [])`)

```
app.controller('demoCtrl', function ($rootScope, $state, $scope) {
//Your controller code
});
```

Last thing

script file including order will be

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Page specific controllers -->
<script src="path/to/Controller1.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/Controller2.js"></script>
```

Regards.

Comment: this didn't work, it kept giving a bunch of erros :/